# How to upgrade my baggage on Qatar Airways

Tags: luggage, qatar-airways

I'm travelling from Singapore to Europe on Qatar airways and would like to upgrade my luggage. How can this be done?

Comment: Have you called Qatar Airways and asked them?

Answer (score 3):

You can buy excess baggage here

https://www.qatarairways.com/en-pk/baggage/excess.html